# how can argparse set default value of optional parameter to null or empty?

Tags: python, argparse

I am using python argparse to read an optional parameter that defines an "exemplar file" that users sometimes provide via the command line.  I want the default value of the variable to be empty, that is no file found.

```
parser.add_argument("--exemplar_file", help = "file to inspire book", default = '')
```

Will this do it?

Answer (score 11):

Just don't set a default:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--exemplar_file', help='file to inspire book')

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.exemplar_file)

# Output:
# None
```

Answer (score 4):

The default `default` is `None` (for the default `store` action).  A nice thing about is that your user can't provide that value (there's no string that converts to `None`).  It is easy to test

```
 if args.examplar_file is None:
     # do your thing
     # args.exampler_file = 'the real default'
 else:
     # use args.examplar_file
```

But `default=''` is fine. Try it.